# Why do i keep getting error in the given python code?

Tags: python, syntax-error

I keep getting a syntax error in line 12 even afer removing the elif block.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    N = int(input())
    l=[]
    for i in range(N):
        op=input().split(' ')
        if(op[0]=='insert'):
            l.insert(int(op[1]),int(op[2]))
        elif(op[0]=='print'):
            print(l)
        elif(op[0]=='remove'):
            l.remove(int(op[1])
        elif(op[0]=='reverse'):
            l.reverse()
        elif(op[0]=='append'):
            l.append(int(op[1])
        elif(op[0]=='append'):
            l.append(int(op[1])
```

Comment: `l.remove(int(op[1])` look closely.....

Comment: Whenever you get a `SyntaxError` it will either be in the line you're shown or a few lines back. Go backwards line-by-line and make sure you have `:` where needed, all your parentheses closed (`[`, `(` or `{`) and that your indentation is good

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Complete the parenthesis everywhere.

```py
if __name__ == '__main__':
    N = int(input())
    l=[]
    for i in range(N):
        op=input().split(' ')
        if(op[0]=='insert'):
            l.insert(int(op[1]),int(op[2]))
        elif(op[0]=='print'):
            print(l)
        elif(op[0]=='remove'):
            l.remove(int(op[1])) #here
        elif(op[0]=='reverse'):
            l.reverse()
        elif(op[0]=='append'):
            l.append(int(op[1])) #here
        elif(op[0]=='append'):
            l.append(int(op[1])) #here
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a closing parenthesis ")" on 3 lines for example here

```py
l.remove(int(op[1])
```

I would suggest to install a python linter that can catch syntax errors.

Answer (score 0):

The error is here my friend:

```
l.remove(int(op[1])**)**
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    N = int(input())
    l=[]
    for i in range(N):
        op=input().split(' ')
        if(op[0]=='insert'):
            l.insert(int(op[1]),int(op[2]))
        elif (op[0]=='print'):
            print(l)
        elif (op[0]=='remove'):
            l.remove(int(op[1])) #you were missing a bracket here
        elif (op[0]=='reverse'):
            l.reverse()
        elif(op[0]=='append'):
            l.append(int(op[1])) #here
        elif (op[0]=='append'):
            l.append(int(op[1])) #here
```